# VS Code create extension that opens a new window for visualization

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

for my current work I am trying to develop a support tool in VS Code. For this I want to write an extension that can show lines and intersections, which are defined in a file with custom syntax, in a kind of canvas.
In my current ideas I would like to have like LaTeX live a "Start" button that then opens a new window and interprets my file.

I don't know where to start looking I only get existing extension suggestions and in the documentation of VS Code I didn't find my way around either.
Any ideas, templates or keywords I can search for would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have a lookt at [Webviews](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). They are the recommended way to implement custom views in VS Code. You might want to implement a [command](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command) that triggers the generation of an image file or HTML to be displayed in your custom view. The command would e.g. access the content of the currently active text document that contains some definition in you your syntax.

Comment: Thank you. Webviews seem to be the answe. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
I have made **great progress** with the extension. If someone has a similar goal I can really recommend reading the docu. 
Webview Docu: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview

Also the Microsoft Markdown extension Github was very helpfull: https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-markdown-mermaid

Now to my procedure:

**1. button that opens the preview**
This can be added very easily in the package.json:

```
"commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.showPreview", // or whatever you want to call it
            "title": "Your Title",
            "category": "Your Category",
            "icon": {
                "light": "/assets/dark-preview.svg", // your path to light and darkmode icon
                "dark": "/assets/light-preview.svg"
            }
        },
```

To give this button a function we now have to register a new command in the activate function

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // ...
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.showPreview', () => { // the name has to be the same as in the package.json
                VisualizeConnectorPanel.createOrShow(context.extensionUri); // I created a class with the template code from the Webview docu of VSCode
    })
    );
    // ...
}
```

**2. Open webview with all resources properly**
Make sure to allow all the local resources you need for the extension. 
I create the folder "js" with all the JavaScript files I needed. And with the following code (from docu template) you can allow those ressources:

```
function getWebviewOptions(extensionUri: vscode.Uri): vscode.WebviewOptions 
{
  return {
    // Enable javascript in the webview
    enableScripts: true,
    // And restrict the webview to only loading content from our extension's `js` directory.
    localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, 'js')] 
    // Notice that I had to concatinate the path with the js folder to allow the js files in the folder
  };
}
```

Additionally, the scripts have to be included in the HTML.
With this meta information you allow to load images, css an js (VScode Docu):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src ${webview.cspSource}; img-src ${webview.cspSource} https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
```

Now the JavaScript files have to be embedded with a nouce and it is a valid webview:

```
<body>
    <!-- .... Generate the Script Uri just like in the VSCode examplel code -->

    <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>

    <!-- .... -->
</body>
```